# Adding field to Qweb report

Tags: odoo, odoo-8, odoo-9

There is field account.move.line.journal_id and i want it to be displayed in report.

i'm trying by

```
<tr t-foreach="p.account_move_line" t-as="p">
                <span t-esc="p.journal_id"/>
                </tr>
```

or something like this.

```
<tr t-foreach="p.account_invoice.payment_move_line_ids" t-as="p">
                <span t-esc="p.journal_id"/>
```

but getting error

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'account_move_line'

Error to render compiling AST
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'account_move_line'
Template: account.report_invoice_document
Path: /templates/t/t/div/div[4]/div[2]/table/tr[2]/td[2]/tr
Node: <tr t-foreach="p.account_move_line" t-as="p">
                <span t-esc="p.journal_id"/>
                </tr>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In t-foreach you must have the list you want to iterate. I think the error is that you are assigning the value to p and at the same time you are iterating by this variable.
Try changing the variable (this is taking into account that p is your account_invoice record, otherwise you can access directly without the t-foreach):

```
<tr t-foreach="p.account_move_line" t-as="j">
    <span t-esc="j.journal_id"/>
</tr>
```

I hope I've helped ;)